# RewriteRules in htaccess for clean URL resolution and redirect from full URL to clean URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm working on a website project, [www.experimonkey.com](https://www.experimonkey.com/). In the root directory, I have directories for experiments, games, etc., that I've been serving dynamically with php. I want to clean up the URLs so that instead of `/experiments?eid=homemade-lava-lamp`, for example, a user can go to `/experiments/homemade-lava-lamp`. I'd also like to have a redirect so that if a user goes to the old link, `/experiments?eid=homemade-lava-lamp`, they will be redirected to the clean link.

I thought I had figured out the first part of the problem with the following code in `/experiments/.htaccess`:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?eid=$1 [L]
```

This works for the dynamic pages; however, I later realized that this would screw up the other, real directories in the `/experiments` folder. For example, the address `/experiments/submit` (which is actually `/experiments/submit/index.php`) redirects to `/experiments/submit?eid=submit`--why, I have no idea.

But also, no matter what combinations of the following code I tried (and all of the other threads and documentation I've read), I could not get the old URL to redirect to the clean URL:

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} eid=(.+)
    RewriteRule .+ https://www.experimonkey.com/experiments/%1 [R=301]
```

RewriteEngine On

## Edit (almost working)

I've worked it out this far. Everything is now mostly working, except the last two parts create an infinite loop and I'm not sure how to fix it.

```
#Ignore existing directories and files unless has query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !eid=(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Redirect and remove query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?eid=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.experimonkey.com/experiments/%1? [R=301,L] 

#Rewrite internally to actual URL
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?eid=$1 [L]
```

Comment: To check whether the requested URI matches onto a physically existing file or folder, you can use a RewriteCond and the `f` and `d` flags.

Comment: Rewriting keeps the original query string, unless you specify a new one (even if empty, so just `?`), or use a flag to specifically prevent that. So your last rewrite shown should only redirect you to `https://www.experimonkey.com/experiments/?eid=homemade-lava-lamp` right now, and then you’d be in an endless loop.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That was super helpful. ```RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f RewriteRule ^ - [L]``` seems to work perfectly for the directory issue. I'm still struggling on the redirect though. I've tried ```RewriteRule .+ https://www.experimonkey.com/experiments/%1? [R=301]``` which I think is what you suggest, as well as [QSD], but to no avail.

Comment: I just edited my post to include the updated code. The redirect was being ignored because for some reason it registered as an existing file, so I added the first line (though I feel there must be a better way to do this). However, now the last two parts are creating an infinite loop and I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out--I hope this can help someone somewhere along the way (I honestly can't believe how long this took me to figure out).

```
#Ignore existing directories and files unless has query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !eid=(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#Redirect and remove query string. 
#First line was the crucial condition to stop loop by checking for internal redirect first.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /?eid=(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.experimonkey.com/experiments/%1? [R=301,L] 

#Rewrite internally to actual URL
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?eid=$1 [L]
```